# Conventional Commit type when upgrading a library dependency

Tags: dependencies, conventional-commits

What is the best [Conventional Commit](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/) type (`fix`, `feat`, `build`, `chore`, `ci`, `docs`, `style`, `refactor`, `perf`, `test`, ...) when upgrading a library dependency? For example:

- [build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#declaring-dependencies): `implementation 'org.json:json:20230618'` → `implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'`
- [Cargo.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html): `hyper = "1.0.0"` → `hyper = "1.0.1"`

Or does it vary depending on the reason? If it fixes something (like security vulnerability), should I choose `fix`? Or if it's just householding and keeping things updated, should I choose `chore`?

Comment: When I update or add dependencies I always use `chore(deps): update/add somepackage`. That’s good enough, maybe it could be good to include in the message something like “Fixes #271” etc